# Drupal 8 - Load Slow

Tags: database, performance, load, drupal-8

Drupal 8 load really slow; front end and back end both are slow. Big pipe is enable by default, but it's still load very slow. I have over thousand of nodes. Anyway can make it load faster?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should try Pantheon:
https://pantheon.io/

It provides two free sandbox websites with the free account.I've been using it for quite some time to host Drupal 8 websites and it has indeed been a great experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use redis cache and cache all blocks within the site.
https://www.drupal.org/project/redis